# Android How to read response of TCP client on port 502

Tags: android, tcpclient, simulator

I am developing an application to send a request to port 502 and want to read the response from the same port.

This is what i tried so far

```
public class Autoamtion extends Activity {

    Socket echoSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Log.v("on create", "on create");
        final ToggleButton fanOn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
        fanOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (fanOn.isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Autoamtion.this, "Fan is On",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.v("on create", "on create");
                    try {
                        echoSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.19", 502);
                        out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(),
                                true);
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                echoSocket.getInputStream()));
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
                        System.exit(1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                                + "the connection to:192.168.1.19");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }

                    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    String userInput;

                    try {
                        while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                            out.println(userInput);
                            System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    out.close();
                    try {
                        in.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        stdIn.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        echoSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(Autoamtion.this, "Fan is Off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

i just installed one [simulator](http://www.plcsimulator.org/downloads/SimSetup.msi?attredirects=0) which opens the port 502. i confirmed that port which gets open after running this [simulator](http://www.plcsimulator.org/downloads/SimSetup.msi?attredirects=0).
i just established the connection with 502 port. i am not getting any response from there.

Please guide me through this so i can make this working. Any advice and help would be appreciated .
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post stackTrace as well, to check what's failling.

At least one thing is not consistent in your information, your refer in the text `port 503` and in your code you are using `echoSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.19", 502);` connecting to port `502`.

Comment: Thanks for answer i just corrected.i am not getting any errors but even i am not getting any response of that simulator.did i am missing something to read responses ?

Comment: Your code is not reading response from simulator. It looks like is just from `System.in` and writing to simulator.

Comment: ohhh okay, i am new to socket programming,can you give me some reference from where i can learn this many things.

Comment: The basic concepts that you should follow are: 1- Add a EditText and a Button to your layout. Enter the test to send to simulator in the EditText and send it when Button is pressed. 2- The socket read is blocking and shoudn't be done in the UI thread, as it will block everything until you receave the answer from the simulator. You need to create a new thread and read the socket in there. The example in http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/ should help you.

Comment: Thanks luis,i will try with this and let you know if i stuck anywhere
Thanks again